# Map a list of POJO to another type of list and then passing them to an add method

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm still learning RxJava and can't seem to solve how to iterate over a list and return a another mapped type of list. There after I'd like to call an add method to add the newly mapped type of list to my database.

If I use `map()` and then `flatMap()` directly after to add the new list to database it works if its a `single object`, but not for lists of stream data. That's why I tried with a `toList()` after `map()`.
I've tried something like this below.

```
public Observable<List<Assignment>> query(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching data remotely...");

    return mRetrofit.create(AssignmentService.class).GET("token")
        .map(item -> mTransformer.transform(item, Assignment.class))
        .flatMap(mAssignmentLocalDataStore::add);
}
```

[image]

Comment: `.toList()` already returns a list... `.flatMap()` does not?

Comment: Also, I doubt you want a List within an Observable. You should probably `return .map()` as an `Observable<Assignment>`

Comment: Are you missing a `subscribe()` call?

Comment: Updating question in a sec.

Comment: What is the return type of `mTransformer.transform()` and the signature of `mAssignmentLocalDataStore::add`?